# How to get color from theme (not current)?

Tags: android

I have some themes in styles, that can be select. And `setTheme(getThemeResId())` in `BaseActivity`. Everywhere I need I get the main color by `?attr/colorPrimary`. But in settings, I want to show all themes colors. Smth like `getColor(R.attr.colorPrimary, R.style.AppTheme1)`. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] attrs = { R.attr.colorPrimary, R.attr.colorAccent, R.attr.colorSecondary };
TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme1, attrs);
int colorPrimary = ta.getColor(0, Color.BLACK);
int colorAccent = ta.getColor(1, Color.BLACK);
int colorSecondary = ta.getColor(2, Color.BLACK);
Log.i("LOG", "colorPrimary as hex:" + Integer.toHexString(colorPrimary));
```